# how to pass param in function while using *ngFor Angular5

Tags: angular5, ngfor, 2-way-object-databinding

I am getting issue to pass param onclick event in Angular5, here is my code:

```
<li *ngFor="let contact of contactList">  
<div class="user_info_block" (click)="getChatmessages($event, {{contact['id']}})" >  
</div>
</li>
```

Thanks
Ritesh

Comment: I'm not sure how your getChatmessages is written, but this would be enough I guess `(click)="getChatmessages($event, contact.id)"`

Comment: that works for me!! thanks @NikhilGoud